# Can't use RelativeSource in binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, relativesource

I'm creating a modal dialog from a window and I need to bind a combo box in the dialog to a view model **but not the one in its own *DataContext***. Instead, I need to bind the combo box to a property in the view model of the window that created the dialog.

The mark-up is as follows.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="Options"
          ItemsSource="{Binding 
            RelativeSource={
              RelativeSource FindAncestor,
              AncestorType=x:Type Window},
            Path=DataContext.AllOptions}"
          ...
          Style="{StaticResource DefaultComboBoxStyle}" />
```

I'm trying to follow the [different suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4450210/1525840) from SO but I'm only landing in the following error. There's also [a list of binding examples](http://druss.co/2013/10/wpf-binding-examples/), which doesn't make me any more clever.

> {"'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '131' and line position '15'."}

And the inner exception is as follows.

> {"Character 'w' was unexpected in string 'x:Type Window'.  Invalid XAML type name."}

I've tried with other thing then *Window*, including the name of the creating window (*ProgramWindow*) but it complained about the same character - "w"! And when I took awhile shot at *x:Type Program* (no w's!) it complained about the character "m", instead.

I'm not sure I understand why, so an explanation on that would be great. Of course, my question is what I'm missing. Should I add anything to the window tag of the dialog? Do I need to tell the computer that the ancestoring window's view model is going to be used as a relative source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type x:Window}}
```

You are missing the Mode= and the braces around the ancestor type. Braces are required for x:Type.

Comment: Hmm... We're getting somewhere now. The curly braces, I missed (must have been tired at 05:00 AM). Once added, the error goes away. However, I still don't get the elements to show in the combo box. (Also, I'm not sure about *Mode* correction and the *x:* in front of *Window* type. The examples don't use it and my intellisense does't like it. Thoughts?