# Binding to a property outside DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I have DataGrid with multiple `DataGridTemplateColumn`. In one of these columns, I have a button that I want to show when the user select the row and also If `CodeFonc` is equal to 1. (CodeFonc is not part of DataGrid/SelectedItem)

**ViewModel:**

```
   private int _codeFonc;
    public int CodeFonc
    {
        get { return _codeFonc; }

        set
        {
            _codeFonc = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange("CodeFonc");
        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
 <MultiDataTrigger>
   <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsSelected}" Value="True"/>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=CodeFonc, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="1" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
   <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible" />
     </MultiDataTrigger>
```

I'm getting CodeFonc from another window but I'm 100% sure that its value is 1 because I confirmed while debugging.

**Most importantly:**
If I ever replace the `CodeFonc` with anything from the DataGrid (SelectedItem) itself, the button will show fine. So my guess is that because the XAML above is inside the DataGrid, its limiting it somehow?

Comment: You need to bind CodeFonc a little different because inside the DataGrid there is no direct access to "global" DataContext-only to local item. Please look into [These-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3920040/binding-to-datacontext-outside-current-itemssource-context) If following these link you are not able to do these let me know I will write a full answer.

Comment: @Kaspar worked! thank you.

Comment: Have you set the `DataContext` in the xaml?

Answer (score 0):

If the `DataContext` has not been set in the xaml, you can set it to the `ViewModel` like so:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

Where `ViewModel` is the name of the ViewModel.