# Silverlight codebehind from XAML

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid, code-behind, datagridtemplatecolumn

I have the following code in XAML:

```
<data:DataGridTemplateColumn>

   <data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

      <DataTemplate>

         <Image x:Name="picture" Width="200" Height="130" Visibility="Visible"/> 

      </DataTemplate>

   </data:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

</data:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

How would do I this in the code behind (C#), without using this XAML code?

EDIT:

Here is the solution I am using:

[Creating a Silverlight DataTemplate in code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59451/creating-a-silverlight-datatemplate-in-code)

This lets me do exactly what I want.

Comment: Probably the problem is only in the DataTemplate. I would use something like XamlReader.Parse().

Comment: Is it at all possible to have two different types of objects in the DataTemplate? For instance, if I want both a Label AND an Image in the cell.

Comment: Yes, it's possible by using Grid or any other panel, and after that you can put any number of controls inside the panel. Also here is my answer where I created DataGridTemplateColumn in code-behind: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254266/datagrid-cell-style-binding/4258484#4258484 . DataTemplate is parsed from XAML.

Comment: Great, I was able to add a Label and Image using a Canvas; but now this is being applied to all rows on the column (because it is a template). It there a way to only apply this template to certain rows in the column, while having a separate template for other rows?

Comment: You can't use two templates, but you can switch panels inside a single template. I've provided more details in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example, you have a simple `DataGrid`

```
    <sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource ImageCellTemplate}"/>
        </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

If you want to have several templates applied to a single DataGridRow, you can change visibility of internal parts inside the template:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageCellTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsImageTemplate}">
                <Image Width="20" Height="20"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Visibility="{Binding IsTextBoxTemplate}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Id}" Foreground="Red"/>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

There is the part with `Image` and the part with `TextBox` that are bound to the properties of an item view model (IsImageTemplate and IsTextBoxTemplate respectively). They are mutually exclusive and panels will not cover each other.

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var items = new List<ItemViewModel>()
        {
            new ItemViewModel{Id = 1, Title="First", IsImage = true},
            new ItemViewModel{Id = 2, Title="Second", IsImage = false},
            new ItemViewModel{Id = 3, Title="Third", IsImage = false}
        };
        this.DataContext = new MainViewModel { Items = items };
    }
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public List<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsImage { get; set; }

    public Visibility IsImageTemplate
    {
        get { return (IsImage == true) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; }
    }

    public Visibility IsTextBoxTemplate
    {
        get { return IsImage == false ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed; }
    }
}
```